# jQuery set href of special anchor to href of next anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, href, attr

I want to find link child `<a>` and attach it to parent `<a>`.
Here is my code.
This returns same link.

html code

```
<div class="wrap">
  <ul class="main-ul">
   <li>
    <a class="child-link" href="link1"></a>
   </li>
  </ul>
  <a class="to-attach" href=""></a>   <<--to be link1
  <ul class="main-ul">
   <li>
    <a class="child-link" href="link2"></a>
   </li>
  </ul>
  <a class="to-attach" href=""></a>   <<--to be link2
  <ul class="main-ul">
   <li>
    <a class="child-link" href="link3"></a>
   </li>
  </ul>
  <a class="to-attach" href=""></a>   <<--to be link3
  .
  .
  .
  .
  .
</div>
```

jQuery code

```
jQuery(".main-ul").append("<a class='to-attach'></a>");  
var link = jQuery(".child-link").attr("href");
jQuery(".to-attach").attr("href", link);
```

please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Is there ever more than one link in the "main-ul"? If so, which link should one use? If not, why have a list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`.attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) with callback function instead `.each()`

```js
$(".to-attach").attr("href", function(){
    return $(this).prev("ul").find(".child-link").attr("href");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <ul class="main-ul">
    <li>
      <a class="child-link" href="link1">child-link</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <a class="to-attach" href="">to-attach</a>   
  <ul class="main-ul">
    <li>
      <a class="child-link" href="link2">child-link</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <a class="to-attach" href="">to-attach</a>   
  <ul class="main-ul">
    <li>
      <a class="child-link" href="link3">child-link</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <a class="to-attach" href="">to-attach</a>   
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Smth like this?

```
$('.child-link').each(function() {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');

    $(this).closest('ul').next('a').attr('href', href);
});
```